# Get system time (not user set time)

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to get system time in Dart ? e.g. in PC, we've a BIOS time which is a true system time (i.e. irrespective of what time the user can manipulate). I would like to know if it is possible to get the BIOS equivalent time in Dart in my Flutter app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think these two are different?

Comment: I am working on an app in which user’s location and time are quite important. And I would like to avoid any time manipulations by the user so that I can get the true time irrespective of what time user has set.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no distinction. You'd need to get the "real" time from a time server or something like that.

Comment: Yes, thanks Gunter. When user is online there’s no problem. I can get the time from server. However, the issue is when user intentionally goes offline and manipulate the time.

Comment: Then you are out of luck.

Comment: Oho ! At least, this is confirmed. Not bad. Thanks Günter. Appreciate your thoughts on this topic. [For now, I have a workaround. I check if either WiFi or mobile data is on (irrespective of internet connection). If that’s in but no internet connection then this means it’s a genuine problem. :-) ]